# jquery ajax statusCode: 502 function never called

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

Is it incorrect to handle 502 errors in the statusCode: setting? For example:

```
        $.ajax({
            url : '/path/to/url/',
            type : 'get',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            statusCode : {
                                502: function(){
                                    steal.dev.log('server stopped');
                                }
                            },
            success : function(data) {            
                            steal.dev.log('ajax success');              
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                steal.dev.log('ajax error');
                            },
            complete : function(data){
                                steal.dev.log('ajax complete');
                            }
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the error handler called?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the only way the function was called was from the error callback. I guess you can't handle 502's from statusCode.